# I will be leave on this Monday. Is it correct?

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality

Can we say

> "I will be leave on this Monday."

Is this sentence  grammatically correct?

Or we have to say

> "I am going for a leave on this Monday."

Comment: _"I will be leav**ing** this Monday."_

Comment: @P.E.Dant - Or, _"I will leave this Monday."_

Comment: @J.R. Yep—the important thing is that we don't use _on_ in this construction.

Comment: @P.E.Dant - Actually, we can: _I am leaving on Monday_.

Comment: Or even _I will leave on Monday_. The important thing is that _on_ and _this_ do not both appear in this construction.

Comment: @Phil14 - I've upvoted your comment, but I still wanted to add that sometimes the _on_ and _this_ will be heard together in conversation. (It's superfluous and unnecessary, but you do hear it every now and then, in contexts such as: _"The Board will be voting [on this Tuesday](http://www.toledoblade.com/Politics/2017/06/06/Lucas-County-Board-of-Elections-may-eliminate-20-districts.html)."_)

Comment: @J.R. By "this construction", I meant the construction with 
"this", as Phil14 says.

Comment: @J.R. Fair point but different context.  "This" is a pronoun for the subject of the voting here, whereas in the other examples, it specifies which Monday is in question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends if *leave* is being used as a verb or a noun.

If *leave* is being used as a verb, then the right way to say this would be something like one of these:

> I will be leaving on Monday.
>   I am leaving Monday.
>   I will leave this Monday.

(Notice how we use *leaving* when a form of *be* is preceding the verb.)

---

Sometimes *leave* can be used as a noun, though. In some job situations, the expression *on leave* means "having an excused (or paid) absence from work". We might use this expression similar to how we would say "on vacation".

To use *leave* as a noun, we would say something like:

> I am going on leave starting Monday.
>   I am starting leave on Monday.
>   I will be taking leave on Monday.

Answer (score 2):

Neither "I will be leave on this Monday." nor "I am going for a leave on this Monday." is correct.

You can say :

1) I will leave this Monday.

2) I am leaving  on Monday.

You can say this way when you are talking about arrangements.An arrangement is is a plan for the future that you have already thought about and discussed with someone else.

3) I am going on leave from this Monday.

It's like the previous one.  But here "leave " is used as a noun.

Answer (score -1):

> I am on leave **this monday**.

or you can say

> **This monday**, I am on leave.

Comment: Welcome to English Language Learners! Please [edit] to include an explanation of *why* this is correct; answers without explanation do not teach the patterns of the language well. See the [Submitting Answers that merely answer the question](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1117) discussion on meta.